# General screen color issue, In particular, hard to tell gray and white apart

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS laptop, nvidia with Windows 10. Last night, all of the sudden something about my screen changed. I may have hit a keyboard shortcut around the bottom left area but I'm not sure. It's difficult to describe precisely what the issue is, so I'll give an example to illustrate:

In Google chrome, you can typically distinguish which tab is open by looking at the top, as the open tab is more enhanced. For some reason, I can barely make out which tab is open as it is only slightly more visible.

To be clear, this isn't a Chrome problem, something changed everywhere, and this is just one illustration.

Also, this isn't about the Windows nightlight or Windows brightness settings (the problem persists independent of brightness settings).

Moreover, if I connect my laptop to a monitor, there is no issue and if I take a screen shot then send it myself on Whatsapp, the issue is not apparent.

Photo of my screen vs a screenshot:

Picture of my screen
[image]

Screenshot of my screen
[image]

Comment: It looks like you've lost some contrast. Do you have Intel, Nvidia, or AMD graphics? From the graphics manufacturer control panel, can you adjust the color calibration to give you better contrast?

Answer (score 0):

Since screenshots are correct, there is nothing wrong with Windows and the display
adapter. The problem must be with the monitor.

I don't see any way that a keyboard key can cause a problem with the monitor.
If you have powered down and up the monitor and the problem is still there,
then there is a problem with the monitor itself.

If this is an external monitor,
try to find on the manufacturer's website a firmware update to the monitor,
to fix a possible firmware corruption.

Otherwise, a repair-shop might help, or it's time for a new monitor.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.It's a laptop screen and not an external monitor. (almost a year old btw).

Comment: It might only be a bad connection.

Comment: So I should take it in to a shop?

Comment: I don't see another option, but wait first for other answers,  in case.